# How to return the result of a PHP array that holds functions?

Tags: php, arrays, function

This is my first attempt using PHP and not very familiar with it. Tried to do some research but couldn't find anything that answers my problem I'm having. I'm trying to invoke a PHP script with the generate function that calls an array that holds multiple functions with each of them supposed to return a unique string result that also contains another function with a specific string result to combine the string return result.

Unfortunately I'm not getting any results being echoed back by using the generate function. What's wrong here and required to make this work?

```php
$patterns = array(
  function () {
    return getClosure() . ".";
  },
  function () {
    return "pattern 1 " . getClosure() . ".";
  },
  function () {
    return "pattern 2 " . getClosure() . ".";
  },
  function () {
    return "pattern 3 " . getClosure() . ".";
  },
  function () {
    return "pattern 4.";
  }
);

function getClosure() {
 return "end";
}

function generate()
{
  global $patterns;

  // The code below is not returning anything...
  echo $patterns[0];
  echo $patterns[1];
  echo $patterns[2];
  echo $patterns[3];

  // The code below works...
  echo $patterns[4]();
}
```

Comment: When you say *Tried to do some research but couldn't find anything that answers my problem I'm having*, don't guess.. [enable error reporting](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php), then you'll see the error: *Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Object of class Closure could not be converted to string*, googling that error will yield the issue https://www.google.com/search?q=Fatal+error:+Uncaught+Error:+Object+of+class+Closure+could+not+be+converted+to+string+site:stackoverflow.com

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Thank you. I'm not very familiar with PHP but appreciate the help. It's my first time using it. Ok so I have added error_reporting(E_ALL); or error_reporting(-1); and neither show any further information in the web developer console or in Visual Code Output. Where do you see this error?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to echo the function itself, rather than the result of the function. In PHP, a function can be invoked by adding parentheses `()` after the function name.

Perhaps, try this instead:

```
echo $patterns[0]();
echo $patterns[1]();
echo $patterns[2]();
echo $patterns[3]();
```

Comment: I didn't know this. This only works on a returning function that does not contain more functions inside that function. I improved the example code to demonstrate where it works on the last pattern.